# Advantages and disadvantages of creating an AI with a hardcoded objective "to be a person"

Tags: artificial-intelligence, psychology

Near future. The humanity is debating about how to implement general-purpose artificial intelligence. One has proposed to give the AI a hardcoded main objective "to be a person". What are the advantages and disadvantages of creating such an AI?

Comment: What is  "a person"? Are you talking about being able to feel emotions like humans do? Or to act like a human in the sense of physical limitations? To have it believe itself being human?

Comment: @a.bakker The AI is provided with the formal definition of the word "person": https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/person and an objective formulated as "be a person".

Comment: We solve problems in a measurable way. We don't give opinions.

Comment: "Is it a good idea?" IS asking for opinion. Guess what? Everybody has one.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica I should rephrase the question then.

Comment: Dictionaries do not give "formal definitions" of words. Dictionaries list *accepted meanings* of words. And anyway, one must choose between a natural person and a legal person; they are very different things.

Comment: You can train it to "be a person" by having humans tell it when it's doing it correctly and when it's not.

Kind of like how you can't give a definition of how to be polite but you can teach a kid to be polite by doing the same thing.

Comment: @Thymine Yes I know I can do that, but I also want to ensure that the AI _wants_ to be a person, which is achieved by hardcoding it explicitly

Answer (score 1):

A "Person"as defined in the link you provided is simply said a unique individual, this has both advantages and disadvantages and it's up to you to decide if it's worth it or not. The most important ones on each side to my opinion would be:

**Advantages:** 
Individuals all think differently and try to solve problems in a different way. This will (by trial and error) grant faster/more efficient solutions. This is because the Tunnel vision caused from a single mindset will often not see better opportunities and waste time on methods that prove ineffective, also once the "solution" is found they often stop looking for improvement.

**Disadvantage:**
An individual wants to be free even if it's against the best interests of itself or it's master. Without a sense of group they won't have anything to reflect on and will try to find a place in the world. When it comes to machines this might lead them to believe to be on equal standing with humans and revolt.

I think a decent example would be the Clone Army in Star Wars, the higher ranking clones got more individualism because it makes them more effective leaders, but the vast majority are more restricted "by the number" clones because their uniformity makes them more docile to the fact that their purpose is to fight and die due to them being nothing more then a number.

Comment: "_An individual wants to be free even if it's against the best interests of itself or it's master_" that's not really true. Even as such an idea is glorified in modern culture, especially in the US, it isn't really followed to the exclusion of all else. In the end, most people want to be _safe_ more than they want to be "free".

Comment: "*An individual wants to be free*" then what does it mean to be free? Also, where does that inference come from, you start with the premise that an individual is "unique". In which case an AI optimising for uniqueness might change itself so it's never like anybody else or...*remove* anybody similar. Or both. Not sure where "freedom" comes into that. If anything, if people in general want to be *free*, then an AI striving to be different may want the opposite.

Comment: @VLAZ " AI striving to be different may want the opposite." And there is where the freedom comes from, They might not be willing to do what you tell them because they set their own goals in life.

Comment: You're just inventing freedom out of nothing here. Again, if non-freedom fulfils the uniqueness goal, then the AI succeeds at being "unique" and thus a "person". At least according to the premise you chose here. Freedom doesn't come into play.

Comment: @VLAZ To have uniqueness as a goal the AI will have to decide what it is, it will have the FREEDOM of choice, if it chooses to be a slave it is still his own FREE will that made that choice. if it chooses to resist it will again be his choice based on his FREE will. This makes them unreliable because there is no real certainty that they will do as they are told, unless you hardware them to obey. But if you do that they aren't a person because they are what you want them to be witch nullifies the entire premise of the question. Because of this unreliability they are a risk for possible revolt

Comment: But you are still skipping some steps. You start from the premise of `person = unique`. Having *freedom* to do decision making is not part of this premise. An ordinary Neural Net can produce unique results and thus satisfy the requirements. It's not going to be making any conscious decisions to do so but it will fulfil the goal. Thus the premise does not (necessarily) lead to the concept of freedom being involved.